# How to configure gitlab runner installed on kubernetes through web UI

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

After connecting a self hosted GitLab to a self hosted Kubernetes cluster and installing the GitLab Runner through the Web UI there is no way to configure it.

I need to add a config to have it run in privileged mode, but so far the documentation I've found has only pointed to config.toml files which I cannot locate on either the GitLab machine or the Kubernetes cluster (another machine)
[image: GitLab runner]

Runner config is missing any way to configure config.toml
[image: Runner config]

So how does one configure the runner installed from the Kubernetes Applications tab?

Or am I required to uninstall this and manually add a runner instead and manually configure that?

Additional question: The web UI only creates one pod, how to request more pods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use [`kubectl`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/#kubectl) and SSH into the gitlab runner Pod. There are great articles out there that show you how to gain access to your Kubernetes cluster through `kubectl`.

Or you will have to SSH into the node that is running your gitlab runner pod. For this you'll again need `kubectl`.

`kubectl get ns`

```
NAME                  STATUS   AGE
default               Active   11h
gitlab-managed-apps   Active   10h
kube-node-lease       Active   11h
kube-public           Active   11h
kube-system           Active   11h
```

`kubectl -n gitlab-managed-apps get pod`

```
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
runner-gitlab-runner-6987ddf6b5-rgjmw   1/1     Running   0          11h
```

`kubectl -n gitlab-managed-apps exec --stdin --tty runner-gitlab-runner-6987ddf6b5-rgjmw -c runner-gitlab-runner -- /bin/bash`

The `config.toml` file can be located in the [following locations](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html) in the container `runner-gitlab-runner`:

- `/etc/gitlab-runner/` on *nix systems when GitLab Runner is executed as root **(this is also the path for service configuration)**
- `~/.gitlab-runner/` on *nix systems when GitLab Runner is executed as non-root
- `./` on other systems

I found the `config.toml` at `~/.gitlab-runner/config.toml`. Run the following command and it will output your current config file.

`cat ~/.gitlab-runner/config.toml`

```
listen_address = ":9252"
concurrent = 4
check_interval = 3
log_level = "info"

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "runner-gitlab-runner-6987ddf6b5-rgjmw"
  request_concurrency = 1
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "******************"
  executor = "kubernetes"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.kubernetes]
    host = ""
    bearer_token_overwrite_allowed = false
    image = "ubuntu:16.04"
    namespace = "gitlab-managed-apps"
    namespace_overwrite_allowed = ""
    privileged = true
    service_account_overwrite_allowed = ""
    pod_annotations_overwrite_allowed = ""
    [runners.kubernetes.affinity]
    [runners.kubernetes.pod_security_context]
    [runners.kubernetes.volumes]
    [runners.kubernetes.dns_config]
```

The GitLab Runner does not require a restart when you change most options. This includes parameters in the `[[runners]]` section and most parameters in the global section, except for `listen_address`. If a runner was already registered, you don’t need to register it again.

GitLab Runner checks for configuration modifications every 3 seconds and reloads if necessary. GitLab Runner also reloads the configuration in response to the SIGHUP signal. [2](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html)

If your `config.toml` is not in the home directory then you'll need to gain root access to the node that is running your pod. You can find the node with the following command

`kubectl -n gitlab-managed-apps get pod runner-gitlab-runner-6987ddf6b5-rgjmw -o yaml | grep nodeName`

```
 nodeName: gke-cluster-1-default-pool-1937372-fhepo
```

Then use your cloud providers instructions on how to SSH into a node.

Comment: If I edit the config.toml in the running pod, when it is recreated, the config won't persist though. Is there a way to find the root config.toml used by the runner? Both k8s and Gitlab are self hosted so root access isn't an issue

Comment: @IsaacN If you installed it from GitLab then it's running in user mode, so root is not really fixing the issue. The runner should be able to pick up the new configuration. Do not restart your pod because if you do, then the config will be reverted to the default one. so what you should do is edit the `config.toml` and make sure you use the commands to write and save on the terminal. Afterwards, you can check the logs of the runner with something like `kubectl logs gitlab-runner-pod -n <your-namespace>` The logs of the runner should display that the new configuration has been loaded.

Comment: I see. is there any way to edit GitLab's default config.toml (and presumably reinstall from the web UI so it reapplies the chart)? seems weird to have to reconfigure the pod if I ever lose power

Comment: @IsaacN Yes. You first uninstall the GitLab from your by using the web UIs. Install the runners using [`helm`](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/kubernetes.html). Have I answered your original question?

Comment: I guess TLDR: web UI config cannot be realistically modified. Just stick with the separate helm chart for gitlab-runner if the config needs to be changed

Comment: That is correct. You will probably have to set up a cache for your runner because there won't be one at the beginning.